# Vertical LinearAxis Label Size in OxyPlot

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

In my WPF application, I am using `OxyPlot.WPF` control for plotting a `LineSeries`.

According to requirement, two separate plots must be there as shown in the following screenshot. The X-Axis for both the plots is a `DateTimeAxis`and the Y-Axis for both the plots is a `LinearAxis`. The values to be plotted can be same/different.

Now the problem I come across is, when I have a big value in my first plot, then the plot area resizes to allocate for the big value. This looks awkward and also difficult to the eye for analysing the values. Can I fix the label size so that both plot areas start from same place?

So far I have tried setting padding for the parent `Grid` container, `Width` for the `LinearAxis`, `MaximumPadding`, `AxisDistance` and `AxisTickToLabelDistance`. But, the `PlotArea` still gets resized.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by setting the `PlotMargin` for `PlotView`.

```
<OxyPlot:PlotView Name="lineSeriesPlotView" PlotMargins="70 2 2 25">
```

Comment: For code-based approach, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25529408/246758